# MySQL query isn't being performed

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a form which I'm getting data from by POST. I am also updating two separate tables using that data, using two queries. my first query runs fine and it inserts data into a table as expected, my second query is almost the same, but inserts data into another table and it doesn't work. My code is like this.

```
 // First good query is here.
 $selected_employee = $_POST['employees'];
 $date = date('y-m-d H:i:s');
 $qry4 = "INSERT INTO employee_leads (emp_id_fk, lead_id_fk, subject_fk, 
 date) 
VALUES ('$selected_employee', '{$_GET['id']}','$subject' , '$date' )";
$result4 = mysqli_query($con, $qry4);

// second query which isn't working
$qryChosen = " INSERT INTO lead_status (lead_id_fk, buss_id_fk, emp_id_fk) 
VALUES ('{$_GET['id']}', '$userid', '$selected_employee') ";
$resultChosen= mysqli_query($con,$qryChosen);
if(!$resultChosen) {echo "Employee record error #400 "; }
```

Seems like it doesn't iterate the `if(!$resultChosen)` statement also, since I'm not getting the echo about the query not getting performed against the database. Thanks.

*EDIT* I've added this code `$rowChosen = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultChosen);` because if there's something wrong with the query it'll show it, and it gave me the error **mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given**
 As far as I know this happens when the query is wrong and I'm not sure what might be wrong there? P.S `$userid` is defined at the top of the page and it should be accessible.

**EDIT-2** added `echo "The wrong is at ". mysqli_error($con);` and it shows absolutely nothing as an error.

Comment: you should be checking for the real errors, if any. You're not doing that.

Comment: also wide open to SQL injection attack

Comment: Bad `buss_id_fk`? Hard to tell without knowing what error you're getting...

Comment: @wogsland I've defined $userid at the very top of the file, so it should have access to it no problem right? And I'm looking up how to get it to report the problem. Thanks

Comment: If you don't post the relevant fragment, it's hard to assume the rest of the code. Please edit accordingly

Comment: I posted a comment up there, do you not know how to do that? You're just commenting for the one left "after" it.

Comment: You have an answer (if it's still there that is); ask them.

Comment: Anyway, it could be me, but it seems the issue is simply a leading space in front and at the end of the second query inside `$qryChosen`

Comment: Btw; [`date - y` returns *"A two digit representation of a year"*](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) - and MySQL given that if your `date` column is of a `DATETIME` type, your `date('y-m-d H:i:s')` failed, unless you're storing it in a `VARCHAR` type of column. [MySQL's `DATETIME` type uses `YYYY-mm-dd 00:00:00`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html). I just thought you might like to know that.

Comment: did you use the .commit command? did you check your connection string? did you check your variable insertion syntax?

Comment: @MortenBork Do you see a transaction in the code? No. So commit makes no sense. Did he check the connection `// First good query is here.` Apperently yes, since his first query is working.

Comment: what *commit* command are you referring to @MortenBork ?

Comment: Question updated. @Fred-ii- Currently the date is being saved YYYY - MM - DD and it's ignoring the H:i:s for some reason. I think because it's being saved in a Date type in the database and that doesn't support time stamps? =) Thanks for bringing it up

Comment: If you don't check errors/logs at least dump stuff to screen.  You can answer your own questions.  `var_dump($qryChosen)` paste output into phpMyAdmin, party like it's 1999.

Comment: @ficuscr I've updated the question with the error, the same error is showing in the log. When var_dump ing the variable you suggested I get this **bool(true)**

Comment: Any ideas why the `if(!$resultChosen) {echo "Employee record error #400 "; }` is being ignored as well? I mean clearly PHP knows there's an error in the query, yet it's not interpreting the if statement.

Comment: @rtfm

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.commit.php

Comment: @MortenBork Just used `mysqli_commit($con);` after `$resultChosen= mysqli_query($con,$qryChosen);` and nothing changed.

Comment: no where does he turn auto commit off, so it will do nothing. @MortenBork

Comment: @rtfm There are a lot of threads out there, where they are unaware of commit, and it's purpose, and especially when working in teams or still in school. 
The mere fact he asked which commit I was talking about, should validate the question.

I don't however have anything valuable to add additionally to the question. It seems like a parameter issue.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the deprecated mysql_query please. Use PDO instead.

```
<?php
 $con = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;", $user, $pw);

// First good query is here.
 $selected_employee = $_POST['employees'];
 $date = date('y-m-d H:i:s');
 $qry4 = "INSERT INTO employee_leads (emp_id_fk, lead_id_fk, subject_fk, 
 date) VALUES (:selected_employee, :get_id, :subject , :date )";
 $result4 = $con->execute(array(
 ":selected_employee" => $selected_employee,
 ":get_id" => $_GET['id'],
 ":subject" => $subject,
 ":date" => $date
 ));
 if($result4) {
 // second query which isn't working
 $qryChosen = "INSERT INTO lead_status (lead_id_fk, buss_id_fk, emp_id_fk) 
 VALUES (:get_id, :user_id, :selected_employee)";
 $resultChosen = mysqli_query($con, $qryChosen);
 $resultChosen = $con->execute(array(
 ":get_id" => $_GET['id'],
 ":selected_employee" => $selected_employee,
 ":user_id" => $userid
 ));
    if(!$resultChosen) {
    echo "Employee record error #400 ";
    }
 }
 $rowChosen = $resultChosen->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
?>
```

Other than that I dont really understand what your question is, please explain it further.

Comment: I am using the `mysqli` library which isn't deprecated bro. Thanks for the total rewrite, I got an error of a `}` when copy pasted, gonna have to look into the code and test it but I'll need time since I've never written in PDO style before. Anyway it shouldn't be a problem to be written in `mysqli` as the library is fine. The problem is that the query in `$qryChosen` isn't working for some reason, which is the question. Thank you.

Comment: Well it's still sql injectable. Maybe it's '{$_GET['id']}' that is producing the error. try '{$_GET["id"]}'. I've never used mysqli but as far as I know it wouldnt be in the string anymore.

Comment: Yeah I know it's SQL injectable. I'm going to use prepared statements once everything is working. Tried removing that variable altogether and got the same result. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

First check for the typo mistakes in tables and columns, then Try to remove blank spaced from your from line `11` and `12`

```
<?php
// First good query is here.
 $selected_employee = $_POST['employees'];
 $date = date('y-m-d H:i:s');
 $qry4 = "INSERT INTO employee_leads (emp_id_fk, lead_id_fk, subject_fk, 
 date) 
VALUES ('$selected_employee', '{$_GET['id']}','$subject' , '$date' )";
$result4 = mysqli_query($con, $qry4);
if($result4) {
// second query which isn't working
$qryChosen = "INSERT INTO lead_status (lead_id_fk, buss_id_fk, emp_id_fk) 
VALUES ('{$_GET['id']}', '$userid', '$selected_employee')";
$resultChosen = mysqli_query($con, $qryChosen);
    if(!$resultChosen) {
    echo "Employee record error #400 ";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: There are no typo mistakes in the query and I'm not sure what you mean by blank spaced? the spaces in the string shouldn't make it invalid if that's what you mean. Thanks.

Comment: If its not typo then ok, blank spaces I ment to say you're using `$qryChosen = " INSERT` so you must remove space between starting double quote `"` and `INSERT` so it will look like `"INSERT` also remove space from between `)` ending double quote `"` and  so it will look like this `)";`

Comment: Done that, and removed the space at the beginning of the string, it had no effect. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: @MarwanAK then you must missing some values which must not be Null in your columns try to `echo $qryChosen;` and see what happens

Comment: I got this when echoing the variable 

**INSERT INTO lead_status (lead_id_fk, buss_id_fk, emp_id_fk) VALUES ('18', '72', '20')** The values 18, 72, 20 are correct.

Comment: I got you, this make some more sense give a try to my updated answer if it works

Comment: I'm not sure what edits you made. I copy pasted your code anyway and I got the same results.

Comment: i just added `if($result4) { .. }`, and also please don't ignore column types of your table `lead_status` double check for their type is defined correctly or your table contains any column which must not be null while adding new record and you;re ignoring it

Comment: `$result4` does indeed work because that table is being updated. I just checked the columns in the table and they're all **Unsigned integers** Good point, though.